# What RFC standards That describe how network headers work at the bit level

Tags: network, networking, rfc

I want to understand more deeply how network headers are constructed at the bit level based on byte ordering, but what standard RFC number explains this?

Comment: You can start with RFC 791, section 3.1

Comment: Internet protocols are not defined in terms of bits, they are defined in terms of bytes.

Comment: thanks for that sir